# need AT-Command to copy files from sd-card

Tags: file, io, modem, at-command

i have usb-modem that i can comunicate with it using AT-Command.
i can send and recive sms using it.
we know that we can insert an SD-Card into the usb-modem and use it as a storage device
 but i been stuck for days searching how i can work on files on sd card using AT-Command??
please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the modem doesn't expose the card as a drive as other USB devices do (e.g cameras, phones, etceteras)?  I can't see a way of retrieving files off it using ATxx commands.

Edit, I did a little digging and found this:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Huawei_E1550_3G_modem#AT_commands

And I am wondering if any of the following can point you in the right direction:

```
AT^U2DIAG=0 - the device is only Modem
AT^U2DIAG=1 - device is in modem mode + CD ROM
AT^U2DIAG=255 - the device in modem mode + CD ROM + Card Reader
AT^U2DIAG=256 - the device in modem mode + Card Reader
AT+CPIN=<PIN-CODE> - enter PIN-code
AT+CUSD=1,<PDU-encoded-USSD-code>,15 - USSD request, result can be found (probably) in /dev/ttyUSB2.
```

So it would appear you can put the device in a card-reader mode using `AT^U2DIAG=256`.  I'd be interested to see if, when you execute this, whether your drive will then be mapped.  I can't really find anything to *get* files off it after you do this.

Comment: it did it as a drive like flash disk and so but i need to be able to work with the files in it using AT-command.

Comment: many thanks for ur help..my problem is i need to copy a file from the sd-card to somewhere else...or even excute an exe on the sd-card  using AT-command and it can do the copy thing

Comment: @Ramah, what is the make of this USB Modem?

Comment: this usb-modem will be placed in a device (pc) which is storing data on the sd card ..then i want to be able using at-command to copy this file to onther pc over network.

Comment: @Ramah, I meant the manufacturer make/model.  It might aid in pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @Ramah, I have updated my answer.  Let me know how that turns out, e.g, if you switch the modem in to modem + card reader mode, do you then get a drive-mapping?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this. The AT command-set is only for doing "phonestuff". Calling, texting (which in itself is an extension), and such.

The usual reason for usb-modems to have built-in storage is so you can store the drivers there. This would let you use the modem on any computer without needing to connect to the internet to get the drivers.

Comment: '''The usual reason for usb-modems to have built-in storage is so you can store the drivers there. This would let you use the modem on any computer without needing to connect to the internet to get the drivers. ''''       the drivers stored in the nand flash..i don't need to insert sd-card to be able to install it  at any pc.

Comment: Then it's probably just handy storage.

Comment: "The AT command-set is only for doing "phonestuff". " also when we insert sd-card into the phone it and read the data stored in it.

Comment: many thanks for ur help..my problem is i need to copy a file from the sd-card to somewhere else...or even excute an exe on the sd-card  using AT-command and it can do the copy thing

Comment: I understand what it is you want to do. But I don't think its possible... Have you seen this? http://3g-modem.wetpaint.com/

Comment: ok..so can i write or read from the nand-flash using AT-Command.

Comment: The nand-flash is probably either read-only, or can only be flashed like you flash a bios. What is the reason for doing all this anyway?

Comment: can i excute an exe file stored in the sd-card??

Comment: No. Only the operating system can execute files. You could use a autorun on the memory card.